# SVN restore dump is not successfully saved

Tags: linux, svn, dump, redhat

I have dumped svn to file phpmyadmin.dump

When i was trying to save dump file to my new repository path with below command line:

```
svnadmin load /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/repository/phpmyadmin/ < /home/admin/phpmyadmin.dump
```

I got this warning message below:

> <<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 1 svnadmin:
>   File already exists: filesystem
>   '/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/repository/phpmyadmin/db', transaction
>   '1-h', path 'CREDITS'
>        * adding path : CREDITS ...

Please help me to solve this problem, thanks.

Comment: Did you check to see if the file did already exist at that location?

Answer (score 0):

When you load a dump, you normally start out with an empty repository. It looks like you're trying to reload your repository into an already existing repository.

```
$ cd /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/repository  #Might as well be where the action is
$ svn create phpmyadmin_new   #You can rename it later
$ svn load --force-uuid phpmyadmin_new < /home/admin/phpmyadmin.dump
```

Now, if you wanted to load this new repository into the current one, you'll have to specify a new blank directory using the `--parent-dir` argument.

Remember: just create an empty repository and don't create any directories in it.